# How can I put a hat on a subscript?

Tags: errors

I want to put a hat in a subscript like this:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
$x_\hat{z}$
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this results in the errror `pdflatex> ! Missing { inserted.` Other compilers produce similar errors. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is easy to guess:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
$x_{\hat{z}}$
\end{document}
```

I have to admit I don't understand why the extra curly braces are necessary...

Comment: Take for example `x_abc`: this will make `a`  a subscript and `bc` normal-sized. You need to write `x_{abc}` to tell LaTeX that `abc` *all* are subscripts. The same reason applies in your example: you need to tell LaTeX, that the whole `\hat{z}` part is a subscript by enclosing it with curly brackets.

Comment: the syntax should _always_ use braces `a_{2}` the fact that sometimes they may be omitted is an accident of the implementation. `x_\hat{z}` is `x_{\hat} z`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I often use `\text` in subscripts, for example in `V_\text{pp}`. This never produced an error, so I sort-of expected `\hat` to work as well...

Comment: Which would be wrong, if the context in which you use that construction is italic the pp comes out italic. Use `\textup` or `\textnormal`. This wrong use of `\text` is number two on my list of most common use errors (the use of ``\\`` in the text being number one)

Comment: the fact that internally `\text` adds braces and that the primitive `_` parsing is quite unlike macro argument parsing so such hidden braces "work" is not something I would ever use in practice. with a macro that takes an argument, `\fbox\text{bb}` would be `\fbox{\text}{bb}` and give an error unlike `\fbox{\text{bb}}` the fact that `_` happens to work is a quirk of the implementation (and a major complication in any tex-to-xxx convertors as it is really hard to see where the subscript ends unless you have a full tex execution engine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The possibility of omitting `{}` is not an accident of the implementation. TeX was designed for humans and it is much more comfortable to read/write `$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$` than `\(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}\)`.

Comment: @wipet I was referring to the fact that `\text` uses explicit `{}` at the outer level in its expansion so that `x_\text a` works but say `x_\fbox a` does not.